# How to change the color of ngb-tabset type="pills"?

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-bootstrap

I'm using angular 6 and ng-bootstrap. I want to change the background color of `<ngb-tabset type="pills">`

```
.nav-fill .nav-link.active {
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-top: 2px solid #20a8d8;
}

.nav-pills .nav-link.active, .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #20a8d8;
}
```

I cannot override those in `component.scss` even if I use `!important` Those are inline styles. I don't know where they are located, searched the whole project couldn't find them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the pills are in a child component ([NgbTabset](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/tabs/api#NgbTabset)), you have to use a [shadow-piercing descendant combinator](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep) to apply the styles. At the present time, Angular recommends using `::ng-deep`:

```
::ng-deep .nav-fill .nav-link.active {
    margin-top: -1px;
    border-top: 2px solid #20a8d8;
}

::ng-deep .nav-pills .nav-link.active, 
::ng-deep .nav-pills .show > .nav-link {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #20a8d8;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-bootstrap-tab-set-issues-b6mq3k) for a demo.