# Background color in NbTabset

Tags: angular, sass, nebular

Good afternoon, I have a problem in `background` setting nebular `NbTabset` in `angular`,
I'm using `nb-route-tabset`, and I can't find a way to add a `status` to it.

my code:

```
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-tabs',
    template: `
        <nb-route-tabset [tabs]="tabs" [activeLinkOptions]="{exact: false}" fullWidth></nb-route-tabset>
    `,
    style: []
})
export class TabsComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
        
    }
tabs:any[] = [
{
 title: 'Tab 1',
 route: 'tab-1',
 responsive: true
},
{
 title: 'tab 2',
 route: 'tab-2',
 responsive: true
}
];

    
}
```

Is currently like this

[image]

What is required

[image]

How do I add the style `background-color: #ffb6b6;` ?

Comment: Fyi, it's redundant to include "tags" in the title as you've already tagged the question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the color of ngb-tabset type="pills"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52132154/how-to-change-the-color-of-ngb-tabset-type-pills)

Comment: @SwissCodeMen I tried but there is no effect

Answer (score 0):

@SwissCodeMen comment helped me understand how I could add a `background` color using the `::ng-deep`

```
::ng-deep .route-tabset {
    background-color: #0d6efd;
    .tab-text{
        color: #fff;
    }
}
```